# Problems While Installing Git in RHEL 7.6

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, git, repository

I am trying to install git and I get the following error though I have a **valid subscription** of the RHEL Client 7.6.

```
No package git available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I ran the following commands:

```
[root@localhost /]# yum-config-manager --enablerepo \*
[root@localhost /]# yum clean all
[root@localhost /]# yum install git
```

This is the output  of my `yum repolist all` command:

```
[root@localhost /]# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                 | 7.3 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                 | 4.7 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                        | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
pgdg10                                                                                                               | 4.1 kB  00:00:00     
pgdg12-updates-testing                                                                                               | 4.1 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-7-desktop-rpms                                                                                                  | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-free-updates                                                                                               | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
(1/12): epel/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                         |  88 kB  00:00:05     
(2/12): google-chrome/primary                                                                                        | 1.7 kB  00:00:05     
(3/12): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                       | 987 kB  00:00:07     
(4/12): pgdg10/7Client/x86_64/group_gz                                                                               |  245 B  00:00:08     
(5/12): pgdg12-updates-testing/7Client/x86_64/primary_db                                                             |  18 kB  00:00:08     
(6/12): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                       | 6.7 MB  00:00:18     
(7/12): rhel-7-desktop-rpms/7Client/x86_64/group                                                                     | 493 kB  00:00:09     
(8/12): pgdg12-updates-testing/7Client/x86_64/group_gz                                                               |  245 B  00:00:16     
(9/12): pgdg10/7Client/x86_64/primary_db                                                                             | 193 kB  00:00:17     
(10/12): rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64/primary_db                                                                    | 251 kB  00:00:07     
(11/12): rhel-7-desktop-rpms/7Client/x86_64/updateinfo                                                               | 2.6 MB  00:00:12     
(12/12): rhel-7-desktop-rpms/7Client/x86_64/primary_db                                                               |  51 MB  00:01:06     
google-chrome                                                                                                                           3/3
repo id                                                                 repo name                                            status
epel/x86_64                                                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64       enabled: 13,051
epel-debuginfo/x86_64                                                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Deb disabled
epel-source/x86_64                                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Sou disabled
epel-testing/x86_64                                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x8 disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x8 disabled
epel-testing-source/x86_64                                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x8 disabled
google-chrome                                                           google-chrome                                        enabled:      3
pgdg10/7Client/x86_64                                                   PostgreSQL 10 7Client - x86_64                       enabled:    544
pgdg10-source/7Client/x86_64                                            PostgreSQL 10 7Client - x86_64 - Source              disabled
pgdg10-source-updates-testing/7Client/x86_64                            PostgreSQL 10 7Client - x86_64 - Source              disabled
pgdg10-updates-testing/7Client/x86_64                                   PostgreSQL 10 7Client - x86_64                       disabled
pgdg12/7Client/x86_64                                                   PostgreSQL 12 7Client - x86_64                       disabled
pgdg12-source/7Client/x86_64                                            PostgreSQL 12 7Client - x86_64 - Source              disabled
pgdg12-source-updates-testing/7Client/x86_64                            PostgreSQL 12 7Client - x86_64 - Source              disabled
pgdg12-updates-testing/7Client/x86_64                                   PostgreSQL 12 7Client - x86_64                       enabled:     27
rhel-7-desktop-beta-debug-rpms/x86_64                                   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop Beta (Debug RPMs) disabled
rhel-7-desktop-beta-rpms/x86_64                                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop Beta (RPMs)       disabled
rhel-7-desktop-beta-source-rpms/x86_64                                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop Beta (Source RPMs disabled
rhel-7-desktop-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64                                Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop (Debug RPMs)      disabled
rhel-7-desktop-extras-beta-debug-rpms/x86_64                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Extras Beta (De disabled
rhel-7-desktop-extras-beta-rpms/x86_64                                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Extras Beta (RP disabled
rhel-7-desktop-extras-beta-source-rpms/x86_64                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Extras Beta (So disabled
rhel-7-desktop-extras-debug-rpms/x86_64                                 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Extras (Debug R disabled
rhel-7-desktop-extras-rpms/x86_64                                       Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Extras (RPMs)   disabled
rhel-7-desktop-extras-source-rpms/x86_64                                Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Extras (Source  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-fastrack-debug-rpms/x86_64                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Fastrack (Debug disabled
rhel-7-desktop-fastrack-rpms/x86_64                                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Fastrack (RPMs) disabled
rhel-7-desktop-fastrack-source-rpms/x86_64                              Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Fastrack (Sourc disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-10-tools-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64             Red Hat OpenStack Platform 10 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-10-tools-rpms/7Client/x86_64                   Red Hat OpenStack Platform 10 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-10-tools-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64            Red Hat OpenStack Platform 10 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-11-tools-debug-rpms/x86_64                     Red Hat OpenStack Platform 11 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-11-tools-rpms/x86_64                           Red Hat OpenStack Platform 11 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-11-tools-source-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat OpenStack Platform 11 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-12-tools-debug-rpms/x86_64                     Red Hat OpenStack Platform 12 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-12-tools-rpms/x86_64                           Red Hat OpenStack Platform 12 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-12-tools-source-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat OpenStack Platform 12 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-13-tools-debug-rpms/x86_64                     Red Hat OpenStack Platform 13 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-13-tools-rpms/x86_64                           Red Hat OpenStack Platform 13 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-13-tools-source-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat OpenStack Platform 13 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-14-tools-debug-rpms/x86_64                     Red Hat OpenStack Platform 14 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-14-tools-rpms/x86_64                           Red Hat OpenStack Platform 14 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-14-tools-source-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat OpenStack Platform 14 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskt disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-7.0-tools-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64            Red Hat OpenStack Tools 7.0 for Red Hat Enterprise L disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-7.0-tools-rpms/7Client/x86_64                  Red Hat OpenStack Tools 7.0 for Red Hat Enterprise L disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-7.0-tools-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64           Red Hat OpenStack Tools 7.0 for Red Hat Enterprise L disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-8-tools-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64              Red Hat OpenStack Platform 8 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskto disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-8-tools-rpms/7Client/x86_64                    Red Hat OpenStack Platform 8 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskto disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-8-tools-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64             Red Hat OpenStack Platform 8 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskto disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-9-tools-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64              Red Hat OpenStack Platform 9 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskto disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-9-tools-rpms/7Client/x86_64                    Red Hat OpenStack Platform 9 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskto disabled
rhel-7-desktop-openstack-9-tools-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64             Red Hat OpenStack Platform 9 Tools for RHEL 7 Deskto disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-beta-debug-rpms/x86_64                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional Beta ( disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-beta-rpms/x86_64                                Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional Beta ( disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-beta-source-rpms/x86_64                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional Beta ( disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64                       Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional (Debug disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-fastrack-debug-rpms/x86_64                      Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional Fastra disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-fastrack-rpms/x86_64                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional Fastra disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-fastrack-source-rpms/x86_64                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional Fastra disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-rpms/7Client/x86_64                             Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional (RPMs) disabled
rhel-7-desktop-optional-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64                      Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional (Sourc disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rh-common-beta-debug-rpms/x86_64                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - RH Common Beta  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rh-common-beta-rpms/x86_64                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - RH Common Beta  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rh-common-beta-source-rpms/x86_64                        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - RH Common Beta  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rh-common-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64                      Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - RH Common (Debu disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rh-common-rpms/7Client/x86_64                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - RH Common (RPMs disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rh-common-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - RH Common (Sour disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhceph-1.3-tools-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64               Red Hat Ceph Storage Tools 1.3 for Red Hat Enterpris disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhceph-1.3-tools-rpms/7Client/x86_64                     Red Hat Ceph Storage Tools 1.3 for Red Hat Enterpris disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhceph-1.3-tools-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64              Red Hat Ceph Storage Tools 1.3 for Red Hat Enterpris disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhceph-2-tools-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64                 Red Hat Ceph Storage Tools 2 for Red Hat Enterprise  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhceph-2-tools-rpms/7Client/x86_64                       Red Hat Ceph Storage Tools 2 for Red Hat Enterprise  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhceph-2-tools-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64                Red Hat Ceph Storage Tools 2 for Red Hat Enterprise  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhn-tools-beta-debug-rpms/x86_64                         RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop Bet disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhn-tools-beta-rpms/x86_64                               RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop Bet disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhn-tools-beta-source-rpms/x86_64                        RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop Bet disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhn-tools-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64                      RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop (De disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhn-tools-rpms/7Client/x86_64                            RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop (RP disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rhn-tools-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64                     RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop (So disabled
rhel-7-desktop-rpms/7Client/x86_64                                      Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop (RPMs)            enabled: 19,274
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6-beta-debug-rpms/x86_64                 Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta (for RHEL 7 Desktop)  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6-beta-rpms/x86_64                       Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta (for RHEL 7 Desktop)  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6-beta-source-rpms/x86_64                Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta (for RHEL 7 Desktop)  disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6-puppet-upgrade-beta-debug-rpms/x86_64  Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta - Puppet Upgrade (for disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6-puppet-upgrade-beta-rpms/x86_64        Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta - Puppet Upgrade (for disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6-puppet-upgrade-beta-source-rpms/x86_64 Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta - Puppet Upgrade (for disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.1-debug-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.1 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (De disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.1-rpms/x86_64                          Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.1 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (RP disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.1-source-rpms/x86_64                   Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.1 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (So disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.2-debug-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.2 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (De disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.2-rpms/x86_64                          Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.2 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (RP disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.2-source-rpms/x86_64                   Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.2 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (So disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-debug-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (De disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-puppet4-debug-rpms/x86_64            Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 - Puppet 4 (for RHEL 7 D disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-puppet4-rpms/x86_64                  Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 - Puppet 4 (for RHEL 7 D disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-puppet4-source-rpms/x86_64           Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 - Puppet 4 (for RHEL 7 D disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-rpms/x86_64                          Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (RP disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-source-rpms/x86_64                   Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (So disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.4-debug-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.4 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (De disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.4-rpms/x86_64                          Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.4 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (RP disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.4-source-rpms/x86_64                   Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.4 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (So disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.5-debug-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.5 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (De disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.5-rpms/x86_64                          Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.5 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (RP disabled
rhel-7-desktop-satellite-tools-6.5-source-rpms/x86_64                   Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.5 (for RHEL 7 Desktop) (So disabled
rhel-7-desktop-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop (Source RPMs)     disabled
rhel-7-desktop-supplementary-beta-debug-rpms/x86_64                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Supplementary B disabled
rhel-7-desktop-supplementary-beta-rpms/x86_64                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Supplementary B disabled
rhel-7-desktop-supplementary-beta-source-rpms/x86_64                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Supplementary B disabled
rhel-7-desktop-supplementary-debug-rpms/7Client/x86_64                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Supplementary ( disabled
rhel-7-desktop-supplementary-rpms/7Client/x86_64                        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Supplementary ( disabled
rhel-7-desktop-supplementary-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64                 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Supplementary ( disabled
rhel-7-desktop-thirdparty-oracle-java-beta-rpms/x86_64                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Oracle Java Bet disabled
rhel-7-desktop-thirdparty-oracle-java-beta-source-rpms/x86_64           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Oracle Java Bet disabled
rhel-7-desktop-thirdparty-oracle-java-rpms/7Client/x86_64               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Oracle Java (RP disabled
rhel-7-desktop-thirdparty-oracle-java-source-rpms/7Client/x86_64        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Oracle Java (So disabled
rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64                                           RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates                 enabled:    246
rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo/x86_64                                 RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates Debug           disabled
rpmfusion-free-updates-source/x86_64                                    RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates Source          disabled
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing/x86_64                                   RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Test Updates            disabled
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-debuginfo/x86_64                         RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Test Updates Debug      disabled
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-source/x86_64                            RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Test Updates Source     disabled
repolist: 33,145
```

I referred this [post](https://www.unix.com/red-hat/236705-solved-cannot-install-git-rhel-6-a.html) and executed the following command to get the same error:

```
[root@localhost /]# yum-config-manager --enablerepo rhel-7-desktop-optional-rpms
```

I am not sure where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the [Developer Toolset](https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/overview/) repo in your list; I'd suggest using the [Getting Access to Red Hat Developer Toolset User Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/7/html-single/user_guide/index#sect-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset-Subscribe) to achieve your goal.

The first step is to get access to the software using either the Red Hat Software Collections or the Red Hat Developer Tools. For example, using the Developer Tools on a RHEL workstation, you'd:

1. enable the repo with: `subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-workstation-devtools-rpms` and then
2. Add the Red Hat Developer Tools key to your system:

   ```
   # cd /etc/pki/rpm-gpg
   # wget -O RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-devel https://www.redhat.com/security/data/a5787476.txt
   # rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-devel
   ```
3. Then install git: `yum install git` or the meta package: `yum install devtoolset-2-vc` or the entire toolset: `yum install devtoolset-2`